# How to consume messages between two timestamps using Kafka Console Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to retrieve messages in Kafka console conumer for a particular timestamp range?

For example kafka messags between 08:00 to 09:00 yesterday.

Comment: How are you consuming the data - which client library / language?

Comment: im using java, but to be honest i want to see the result in terminal and not change the java code

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`kcat`](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat) for consuming messages between two timestamps:

```
kcat -b localhost:9092 -C -t mytopic -o s@1568276612443 -o e@1568276617901
```

where

- `s@` denotes the starting timestamp in ms
- `e@` denotes the ending timtestamp in ms (non-inclusive)

Comment: `s@1568276612443` , is this milliseconds from start of the day??

Comment: @Hummingbird It's a timestamp. You can use any timestamp you wish. `s@` denotes the starting timestamp and `e@` denotes the ending timestamp.

Comment: yes,but the  number `1568276612443`, what is this?? a millisecond or nanosecond and if yes , from when does it began?? start of the day or start of some particular day??

Comment: @Hummingbird OK. What is the timestamp interval you want to consume from?

Comment: that's ok , i found the timestamps i wanted . anyways the server i wanted to implement the command does not have kafkacat.

Comment: FWIW, this does not seem to work (anymore?). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853753/kafkacat-consume-between-timestamp-giving-wrong-results-when-counting-records/73854735?noredirect=1#comment130412289_73854735) question as well as the corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat/issues/399).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it since [Kafka version 0.10.1](https://www.confluent.io/blog/announcing-apache-kafka-0-10-1-0/).
Use the function `offsetsForTimes` in [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes(java.util.Map)):

> Look up the offsets for the given partitions by timestamp. The
>   returned offset for each partition is the earliest offset whose
>   timestamp is greater than or equal to the given timestamp in the
>   corresponding partition. This is a blocking call. The consumer does
>   not have to be assigned the partitions.

Comment: hey ofek , i was actually looking to be done in terminal , using the kafka-console-consumer shell script

Comment: You can use `KafkaConsumer` api just to retrieve the relevant offset, then use `--offset myoffset` in the `kafka-console-consumer`, I don't think there is other solution rather than use `--property print.timestamp=true` in `kafka-console-consumer` and filter the printed time for each message using `grep` in order to fit your range.  If this is a good direction for you I can write it in more details.

Comment: Or, if your brokers can talk PLAINTEXT, you can use one of Kafka tools to get the offset by timestamp: `kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell ... --time <Long: timestamp>`. Then, pass that offset to kafka-console-consumer.

Comment: @OfekHod but wouldn't i be still using an api??

Answer (score 0):

refer: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#id14

```py
from confluent_kafka import Consumer,KafkaError,TopicPartition
import argparse
import os

broker_list = '10.100.110.35:9092'
group = 'kcat_consumer'

consumer_conf = {'bootstrap.servers': broker_list,
                     'group.id': group,
                     #  'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
                     'enable.auto.commit': False,
                     }
consumer = Consumer(consumer_conf)

partition = 0
timestamp_ms = 1618258800000
timestamp_offsets = {partition: timestamp_ms}
topic = 'hw-blacklist-1195'
tp = TopicPartition(topic, partition, timestamp_ms)
offsets = consumer.offsets_for_times([tp])
print(offsets[0].offset)

consumer.assign([TopicPartition(topic,0,offsets[0].offset)])
while True:
    msg = consumer.poll(1.0,)
    if not msg:
        print(msg)
        break
    
    print(msg.value())
```