# Get Kafka messages between two datetime from a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

what command to use if I want to consume messages between two specific dates like 20 Feb 00:00:00 and 22 Feb 00:00:00 from a Kafka topic ?
All  I know is  that there is consumer groups command in which we can give "**--to-datetime**" ,"**--by-duration**" etc.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
--group test-group --reset-offsets --all-topics --to-datetime 2021-02-20T00:00:00.000
```

But how can I stop that consumer group when it reaches a particular datetime (2021-02-22T00:00:00.000)?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to consume messages between two timestamps using Kafka Console Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882882/how-to-consume-messages-between-two-timestamps-using-kafka-console-consumer)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [`kafkacat`](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat)

```
kafkacat -b mybroker -C -t mytopic -o s@1568276612443 -o e@1568276617901
```

Where the two timestamps are specified as [milliseconds since the Unix epoch](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for this but I don't have kafkacat on my servers and sadly can't download it also , can you help with some other utility that gets shipped with confluent platform?

Comment: Is there any equivalent command for kafkacat in windows?

Comment: @Pra_A you can run Kafkacat under Docker on Windows