# Start streaming Kafka from a specific timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka

This tutorial [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/#install-java) shows the command to consume kafka topic in a terminal.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic topic_name --from-beginning --bootstrap-server IP:port
```

What would be the syntax if I want to start streaming from a specific timestamp, and not `--from-beginning`. And what format should the timestamp be in (i.e. long epoch or GMT yyyymmdd hhmmss, etc)

Comment: relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882882/how-to-consume-messages-between-two-timestamps-using-kafka-console-consumer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to consume messages between two timestamps using Kafka Console Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882882/how-to-consume-messages-between-two-timestamps-using-kafka-console-consumer)

Comment: It's not possible with the java cli. You need to create a consumer group, use `offsetsForTimes` (mentioned in the other post), commit those offsets to that group, then consume using that group name. Since the group would hold offsets, using the `auto.offset.reset` property flags would be ignored