# Kafkacat consume between timestamp giving wrong results when counting records

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I want to count the number of messages in a given Kafka topic between two timestamps. I tried doing this using `kafkacat`, using the following command:

```bash
# START_DATE = 01.04.2022 02:00:00Z
# END_DATE = 01.04.2022 02:05:00Z
$ kafkacat -C -b broker:9092 -t mytopic -o s@1648778400000 -o e@1648778700000 -p 0 -f '[ts %T] [partition %p] [offset %o] %k\n' -e -c 1
```

In fact, this is the same approach that is listed as the answer in a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60884850/991710).

According to `kafkacat --help`:

```
Consumer options:
  -o <offset>        Offset to start consuming from:
                     beginning | end | stored |
                     <value>  (absolute offset) |
                     -<value> (relative offset from end)
                     s@<value> (timestamp in ms to start at)
                     e@<value> (timestamp in ms to stop at (not included))
```

Correspondingly, I would expect the above command to give me the first record that has a timestamp *greater* than `s@<value>` and *smaller* than `e@<value>`. However, it instead gives me a record that has a timestamp *prior* to `s@<value>` (in fact, it just gives me the first record in partition `0`):

```bash
# output of above command
[ts 1648692486141] [partition 0] [offset 2] 643b0013-b3e1-47a5-a9d3-7478c0e91ca4
```

Am I misunderstanding the consumer options `s@<value>` and `e@<value>`?

Kafkacat version:

```bash
Version 1.5.0 (JSON, librdkafka 1.2.1 builtin.features=gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,sasl_oauthbearer)
```

---

Additionally, I'm seeing some odd behaviour even with *just* `s@<value>`. For example:

```bash
kafkacat -C -b broker:9092 -t mytopic -o s@1648778400000 -p 0 -f '[ts %T] [partition %p] [offset %o] %k\n' -e -c 1
```

should, as I understand it, output the first record with `record.timestamp ≥ 1648778400000`. The actual output is different:

```
[ts 1648692486141] [partition 0] [offset 2] 643b0013-b3e1-47a5-a9d3-7478c0e91ca4
```

and contains a timestamp prior to the one I set (`31.03.2022 02:08:06Z` vs. `01.04.2022 02:00:00Z`).

This output is the same when I tested using `docker run edenhill/kcat:1.7.1` (the above was an Ubuntu `kafkacat`)

Comment: For the record, since this seems like a bug, I have raised an issue over at the [kcat issue tracker](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat/issues/399) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can provide `-o` multiple times. Therefore, your options include

```
-o e@1648778700000 -p 0  -c 1
```

To read one message from partition 0, which is less than timestamp 1648778700000

---

To properly consume between timestamps, find the offsets for the start timestamp, commit them to a consumer group, then start a consumer in the group with your end timestamp

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a bummer. However, this doesn't quite explain why I'm getting the record that I'm getting even with just `s@<value>`. I've updated the question with some more details.

Comment: That's my understanding of `s@` as well, so not really sure. Perhaps a version issue? Your Docker image is 1.7.1, and the output you show has 1.5.0 ... Also, I could totally be wrong since the last example at the bottom shows the syntax you've given https://github.com/edenhill/kcat#examples

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear: I tried both a local `1.5.0 kafkacat` and also the `1.7.1 kcat` docker one. But that's quite peculiar then. Ill try opening an issue on the tracker in that case. Thanks for the help nonetheless.